# Добавить html код в меню wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Пытаюсь вывезти в двухуровневом меню ссылку на все услуги данного меню, но никак не получается, как это можно сделать?
Вот как хочу

```
<li class="nav-list__item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-list__link">Гидроизоляция </a>
                        <span class="nav-list__icon"></span>
                        <ul class="nav-sublist">
                            <li class="nav-sublist__item">
                                <p class="nav-sublist__title">Популярные услуги:</p>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-sublist__item">
                                <a href="#" class="nav-sublist__link">Гидроизоляция кровли</a>
                            </li>
                                                           <li>
                                <a href="#" class="nav-sublist__button">Посмотреть все услуги</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
```

Делаю так, но никак переменная yo не хочет работать

```
class My_Walker_Nav_Menu extends Walker_Nav_Menu {

    // add classes to ul sub-menus
    function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = NULL ) {
        // depth dependent classes
        $indent = ( $depth > 0  ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '' ); // code indent
        $display_depth = ( $depth + 1); // because it counts the first submenu as 0
        $classes = array(
            'sub-menu',
            ( $display_depth % 2  ? 'menu-odd' : 'menu-even' ),
            ( $display_depth >=2 ? 'sub-sub-menu' : '' ),
            'nav-sublist'
        );
        $class_names = implode( ' ', $classes );

        // build html
        $output .= "\n" . $indent . '<ul class="' . $class_names . '"><li class="nav-sublist__item">
                                <p class="nav-sublist__title">Популярные услуги:</p>
                            </li>' . "\n";
    }

    // add main/sub classes to li's and links
    function start_el( &$output, $data_object, $depth = 0, $args = null, $current_object_id = 0 ) {
        global $wp_query;

        // Restores the more descriptive, specific name for use within this method.
        $item = $data_object;

        $indent = ( $depth > 0 ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '' ); // code indent

        // depth dependent classes
        $depth_classes = array(
            ( $depth == 0 ? 'nav-list__item' : 'sub-menu-item' ),
            ( $depth >=2 ? 'sub-sub-menu-item' : '' ),
            ( $depth % 2 ? 'menu-item-odd' : 'menu-item-even' ),
            'menu-item-depth-' . $depth
        );
        $depth_class_names = esc_attr( implode( ' ', $depth_classes ) );

        // passed classes
        $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
        $class_names = esc_attr( implode( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item ) ) );

        // build html
        $output .= $indent . '<li id="nav-menu-item-'. $item->ID . '" class="' . $depth_class_names . ' ' . $class_names . '">';

        // link attributes
        $attributes  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? ' title="'  . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->target )     ? ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target     ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? ' rel="'    . esc_attr( $item->xfn        ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->url )        ? ' href="'   . esc_attr( $item->url        ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ' class="menu-link ' . ( $depth > 0 ? 'nav-sublist__link' : 'nav-list__link' ) . '"';

        $item_output = sprintf( '%1$s<a%2$s>%3$s%4$s%5$s</a>%6$s<span class="nav-list__icon"></span>',
            $args->before,
            $attributes,
            $args->link_before,
            apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ),
            $args->link_after,
            $args->after
        );
        $yo = '<li><a href="' . $item->url . '" class="nav-sublist__button">Посмотреть все услуги</a></li>';
        // build html
        $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args, $yo );
    }

}
  function my_nav_menu( $args ) {

    $args = array_merge( [
        'container'       => 'div',
        'container_id'    => 'nav__wrapper',
        'container_class' => 'nav__wrapper',
        'menu_class'      => 'nav__list nav-list',
        'echo'            => false,
        'items_wrap'      => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
        'depth'           => 10,
        'walker'          => new My_Walker_Nav_Menu()
    ], $args );

    echo wp_nav_menu( $args );
}
```